# Postgres PENULTIMATE LAST_VALUE() for cursor based pagination

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pagination, rows

Let's say I have this table:

```
+--------+----------+
| ID     | Name     |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | John     |
+--------+----------+
| 2      | Mike     |
+--------+----------+
| 3      | Bob      |
+--------+----------+
```

I'm trying to paginate with a cursor approach (Relay/GraphQL).

Now if a user asks for players from ID 1 to 2 I need a way to understand if in table there are more players.

And I think a way is to use `LIMIT` 2 (last ID requested) + 1 = 3.

So I use this query:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "players"
  LIMIT 3
```

In my back-end code I remove the last row and evaluate `hasNextPage` to true and cursor content (ID 2).

I'm trying to find a way to use SQL to do this heavy work.

Can I create a `OVER ()` (virtual) column using something like the below code?

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    LAST_VALUE ( ID ) OVER ( ) AS pageInfo
FROM
    "players"
  LIMIT 3
```

It works but `LAST_VALUE( ID )` shows me the 3rd ID not the 2nd one I need for cursor content.

**Is there a way to get the PENULTIMATE `LAST_VALUE ( ID )`?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth_value()`:

```
SELECT p.*,
       LAST_VALUE ( ID ) OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) AS pageInfo,
       NTH_VALUE(ID, 2) OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) as page_Info_penultimate
FROM "players" p
LIMIT 3;
```

Note that `LAST_VALUE()` with no `ORDER BY` returns an *arbitrary* value.  It might look like it is the "last value", but that is a coincidence and not guaranteed.

Similarly, `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` returns *arbitrary rows*.  It might look like the first three or last three, but that is a coincidence and not guaranteed.

Using `LAST_VALUE()` like this seems arcane . . . `MAX()` seems more colloquial:

```
SELECT p.*,
       MAX ( ID ) OVER () AS lastvalue,
       NTH_VALUE(ID, 2) OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) as penultimatevalue
FROM "players" p
LIMIT 3;
```